SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110)
Recently, I am doing Flutter compatibility verification on Android 15(<15 is OK), when I upload image, it will sometimes report: 2024-08-13T16:14:21.838249 - [ERROR] [NET] NoNetworkError - ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address =xxx.com.cn, port = 56160, uri=https://xxx/v1/enrollment/upload-img on Request: POST https://xxx/enrollment/upload-img  CorrelationId: a259e1f3-a541-416d-9097-4c34d7a640e0.
I have this issue with http:v1.2.2, my flutter version is 3.19.5.
I have looked for many similiar issues in StackOverflow/Github Flutter Repo/Github Http Repo, however, no solution to this issue(add 'uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"' not work).
Is there more infomation about this issue, can someone help me, thanks a lot?

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

It has nothing to do with the http network library, but with the flutter library image_picker that I use. I just changed the image library. As for why image_picker's image selection affects the network, it is still under investigation.
